# Drupal issue when domain changed

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I created a new website on a temporarly subdomain. When I was ready I changed the settings of the www-domain,to redirect to my new location on my server. After this, it seems that drupal can't find my custom twig templates and uploaded images. when I use new.domainname, images are loaded, but not www.domainname.

How do you normally change the domainname correctly?